# People "don't" pay money to watch movies today. - Do I use the present tense if it's just an one-time event?

Tags: tense

If it is just a one-time thing, do we use the present simple tense?

**Example 1**

Today people have a strike which is not a regular event, and I want to talk about this.

Do I use the present tense?

> A: People **don't work and go on** the streets protesting today.

**Example 2**

Today the school has an event and it is not a regular event.
With this event, we have shuttle buses.

Do I use the present tense?

> A: We **have** shuttle buses today.

**Example 3**

Today the movie theater has an event and it is not a regular event.
We do not need to pay money to watch movies.

Do I use the present tense?

> A: Why **don't** people pay money for movies?

> B: People **don't** pay money to watch movies today.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that for temporary things with *action verbs*, we use present continuous. For everything else, we use present simple.

Example 1 is not a regular event, and the verbs "work" and "go" are *action verbs*, so we use present continuous:

> People **aren't going to work, and are going into** the streets protesting today. (slightly modified to make it sound natural)

Example 2 is not a regular event, but the verb "have" is a *state verb* (not an action verb), so we cannot use the continuous. It is correct.

Example 3 is the same situation as example 1, where the verb "pay" is an action verb, so we should use present continuous:

> A: Why **aren't** people **paying** money for movies?

The second part isn't natural though. Likely, it should read like this:

> B: People **don't have to pay** money to watch movies today.

This is present simple because "have to" is a state verb, so cannot be continuous.